# In Libgit2sharp, is there any way to revert some files' change (Not commited)?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

In other source code control, this operation is called revert or undo.

In Git, I can use

> "git checkout file_paths"

to obtain similar functionality.

But in Libgit2sharp, I'm not able to find similar functionality, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jamill had just made available this feature a few days ago:

- See the **[featured commit](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commit/7e5bbbf17cf27a5c5d0e60670a6c33942ff69cce)**

`repo.CheckoutPaths()` will refresh the content of the working directory to match the version of files from a specific tree-ish.